# how to remove tax rate and tax amount column from checkout cart in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I am working on magento cart and i have to remove the tax column from the checkout cart. I have removed it from header by editing cart.phtml but the rows are rendering from other file which i am trying to figure out. If any one can point me in direction it will be a great help.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to edit cart item template

normally located here by default:
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml